# Building image gallery with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I am trying to build an image gallery for my personal site. Everything is working fine except for two things.

1. Some white dots are occurring near and inside the image gallery.
2. Some images are not fitting inside the block.

One can see both the problems by visiting my [personal site](https://codophobia.github.io/) and then walking to the bottom of the site. I am not able to figure out why this is happening for some images.

One can see that the images in 2nd row don't fit into the block and there are some white dots too.

/_includes/gallery.html

```
<ul class = "photo-gallery">
{% for image in site.static_files %}
    {% if image.path contains 'gallery' %}
       <li><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}" alt="image" /></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

/css/grayscale.css

```
.photo-gallery li {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}


.photo-gallery li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/codophobia/codophobia.github.io)

Comment: you can remove the white dots by resetting the display settings for `<li>` You can do that like so: `ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}`

Comment: @ILoveCSS That was really a very silly mistake :)

Comment: Also your images looks ok not distorted from their place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the dots you can use:

```
.photo-gallery {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

for IE9 you need to add the list-style-type to li as well

for the image you could try something like:

```
<li style='background-image: url("{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}");' ></li>
```

Comment: What about fitting the image inside the block?

Comment: For fitting images, I use the background-image in css instead of  the <img> tag. It seems to work much better. You can then use background-size etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.photo-gallery {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The down images are fitting correctly, the problem is they have a black big border.

To remove the dots take away the `list-style-type`:

```
ul.photo-gallery {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look, maybe this is nice for you:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.photo-gallery {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.photo-gallery li {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul.photo-gallery li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="photo-gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%201&w=150&h=150">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%202&w=150&h=150">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%203&w=150&h=150">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%204&w=150&h=150">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%205&w=150&h=150">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%206&w=150&h=150">
  </li>
</ul>
```